Solvability by radicals, but you don't get to choose the roots
It is well-known that a polynomial equation $P(X)=0$ over a field $K$ is solvable by radicals if and only its Galois group is solvable. Here, "solvabile by radicals" is taken to mean that all roots of $P$ lie in the smallest extension $K^{\text{solv}}$ of $K$ such that every nonzero element of $K^{\text{solv}}$ has exactly $n$ $n$-th roots in $K^{\text{solv}}$.
One could give it another meaning, though. One where one does not get the roots of unity for free: I think of it as a game where a demon chooses the "wrong roots" each time you try to take an $n$-th root, so that if you try to take the $n$-th root of $1$, you will always get $1$, for example...
Definition: Say that $L$ is a very-solvable extension of $K$ if every element of $L$ has an $n$-th root in $L$, for all $n \geq 1$.
Question: Is there a "simple" criterion (say, a group-theoretic property in terms of the Galois group of the splitting field) to determine whether the equation $P(X)=0$ has a root in every very-solvable extension of $K$? (i.e., whatever roots the demon chooses, you will always be able to define some root of your polynomial using them)
I was not able to think of anything smart to say about the situation, apart from the obvious fact that for quadratic/cubic/quartic polynomials both notions coincide (and also, for example, you get $n$-th roots for free when the regular $n$-gon is constructible with ruler and compass).
I don't even understand how different a very-solvable extension $L|K$ could be from $K^{\text{solv}}$, apart from the fact that the Galois closure of $L$ is $K^{\text{solv}}$. Constructing such an extension $L|K$ without accidentally adjoining roots of unity seems to require some "compatibility", which I am not even sure is possible.
So maybe this problem is equivalent to the usual notion...
I have absolutely no doubt that this question has already been asked, as it seems quite natural.
However, I was not able to find any mention of this problem when trying to search on Google or here.

Nice! I really should have seen that... (this is essentially how I noticed that it was okay for Fermat primes based on the n=2 case, I feel ashamed that I didn't think to do the step beyond)
